# Grab Frame VideoToGif in Android

Tags: android, video, javacv, javacpp

I'm trying to grab frames from an Video file in android, the only alternative (tha is already compiled an ready for use) is the [videoToGif](http://code.google.com/p/videotogif/) Project. It uses JavaCV, JavaCpp and Java SE inside Android! The final apk is really big, but I'm doing just an academic project...

**ERROR**
I'm using the follow code:

```
ModifiedFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new ModifiedFrameGrabber(VIDEO_PATH);
IplImage frame = null;

try
{
    frameGrabber.start();
    frame = frameGrabber.grab();
} catch(Exception e){...}

byte[] data = frame.getByteBuffer().array();
```

In the last line I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.protectedArray(DirectByteBuffer.java:292)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:144)
    at my.package.onCreate(MyClass:x)
```

Anyone can help me with that? It seems that the proble is in Java API...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct NIO buffers don't have an array. Call `get()` instead of `array()`.

Comment: hi samuel i want to create video from images by using javacv.is it possible?